# Laravel 5.2 IF Statement Syntax, Change Name based on Value

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, if-statement

So, I'm going to moving on from PHP native to Laravel framework.
See the code below, it's must be error, but this would tell you what I want. I'm confused to the IF statement in Laravel based my database.

```
<td>
        {{ 
        @if($book->status==1)
            echo 'Available';
        @elseif($book->status==2)
            echo 'Lost';
        @else
            echo 'Not Available';
        @endif
        }}
</td>
```

Is that possible to print out the name based on database, example: if the value is 1, then I'll print out 'Lost' on my website? Thank you.

Comment: You should 're-choose' best answer to Joseph Silber 's one. He answered earlier, gave you an option with a getter (which you said you will use). 73bad's answer posted later and doesn't add anything to Joseph Silber's one.

Comment: Yeah, I already realized it before when I reload this page, and I have re-choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<td>
    @if ($book->status == 1)
        Available
    @elseif ($book->status == 2)
        Lost
    @else
        Not Available
    @endif
</td>
```

---

A better place for this would be in the book model itself:

```php
public function getAvailabilityAttribute()
{
    if ($this->status == 1) return 'Available';

    if ($this->status == 2) return 'Lost';

    return 'Not Available';
}
```

Then you could use it directly in your view:

```html
<td>{{ $book->availability }}</td>
```

Comment: It's works! Thanks for the suggest too. Yeah, I'll put it on the model, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
<td>       
    @if($book->status==1)
        {{ 'Available' }}
    @elseif($book->status==2)
        {{ 'Lost' }}
    @else
        {{ 'Not Available' }}
    @endif
</td>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, Your code is working too, with or without {{}}.